# Was Enterprise the only Star Trek show to have different intro credits during mirror universe episodes?

Tags: star-trek, mirror-universe

In Enterprise, the credits at the beginning of episodes with the mirror universe are different. Did any other Star Trek series have altered introduction scenes during mirrored universe episodes, or for other special kinds of episodes?

Comment: Nope. Just that one.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/crazycredits

Comment: Should add the the mirror-verse episode of Enterprise took place _entirely_ in that Universe.  No one had crossed over from the normal universe.  The entire episode is literally "Meanwhile, in a parallel universe..."

Comment: Because there was no crossover from the Prime Universe USS *Enterprise* crew was the explanation for the different credits; the story was told entirely from the POV of the Mirror Universe characters, so it's appropriate the credits change to reflect that because they aren't really "our" crew. In TOS/DS9/Discovery, that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the 4 Star Trek series that include episodes in the mirror universe, Enterprise is the only one to include a unique intro related to the mirror universe.

As for more general changes, there are no other intros that had significant thematic changes. As pointed out in the comment above, some episodes had minor differences like the direction the credits moved, but nothing very noteworthy.